# Hive - Select amount of entries

Tags: hive

I am working in Hive. So far its really great but I have a problem regarding a query.

I have two tables called 'marked' and 'data' and want to extract data from both with one query.

First I want to extract the mindate from table 'marked' and count the entries in table 'data' between the mindate (obtained from 'marked') and the current date.

So I want to get one result containing the userID, the mindate and the number of occurrences of this userID of the other table between the mindate and the current date. 
I try to get this query since hours but Joins as I know them are not working. Can anybody help me out?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I was a little bit in hurry yesterday. Blame on me that I forgot some details.

About the schema:

1. The table marked has just some columns. In total 8. Here is the schema of this table:

   ```
   "name": "Datetime",
   "type": "long",
   "logicalType": "timestamp-millis",

   "name": "Hour",
   "type": "string",

   "name": "UserId64",
   "type": "long"

   "name": "MemberId",
   "type": "int"

   "name": "SegmentId",
   "type": "int"

   "name": "IsDailyUnique",
   "type": "boolean"

   "name": "IsMonthlyUnique",
   "type": "boolean"

   "name": "Value",
   "type": "int"
   ```
2. The schema of the other table called data is a little bit more difficult since this table contains more than 100 columns. To keep it simple I outline just the important columns:

   ```
   "name": "Datetime",
   "type": "long",
   "logicalType": "timestamp-millis",

   "name": "Hour",
   "type": "string",

   "name": "UserId64",
   "type": "long"

   "type": "enum",
   "name": "EventType",
   "symbols": ["IMP", "CLICK", "PC_CONV", "PV_CONV"]
   ```

So if I do a query like the following I get a list with the result

> select timestamp(datetime), hour, userid64, segmentid, isdailyunique,
>   ismonthlyunique, date from marked where userid64 = 8012570064195370898
>   and segmentid = 1878696 order by datetime desc;

The resulting table contains the data. Now I want to use the oldest obtained date for my further query.

If we go to table data and do the following query

> select timestamp(datetime), auctionid64, hour, eventtype,
>   mediacostdollarscpm, buyerspend, buyerbid, ecp, eap, isimp, isclick,
>   userid64, sellerid, publisherid, siteid, sitedomain, advertiserid,
>   advertiserfrequency, advertiserrecency, campaigngroupid, campaignid,
>   creativeid, creativefreq, creativerec, pixelid, dealid, dealtype,
>   custommodelid, custommodellastmodified, leafname, datetime from data
>   where userid64 = 8012570064195370898 and advertiserid = 327758 order
>   by datetime desc;

you will get the results as seen below

```
2016-08-09 19:33:45.0   5908114946988383281 17  PV_CONV
2016-08-07 19:17:13.0   5908114946988383281 17  IMP
2016-08-07 19:16:29.0   5454485145188351263 17  IMP
2016-08-07 18:52:40.0   1074433759230515153 16  IMP
2016-08-07 18:52:40.0   6991642005216308404 16  IMP
2016-08-07 18:52:13.0   5024645171257244072 16  IMP
2016-08-07 18:51:55.0   5371107932239703086 16  IMP
2016-08-07 18:51:55.0   7321752276741166764 16  IMP
2016-08-07 18:51:01.0   3459181835067844898 16  IMP
2016-08-07 18:50:42.0   6208818658549255015 16  IMP
2016-08-07 18:50:41.0   5373958128201701132 16  IMP
2016-08-07 14:34:07.0   8393280749656213703 12  IMP
```

The import line here is the second line. One after there is a sign called "PV_CONV".

What I want:

I want a query which generates me a table containing

- userid
- min date of the table marked
- max date of the table data containing the event_type "IMP"
- time difference between marked date and max date of the table data
- and some other columns of the table data.

Is there any chance to get this without creating additional tables?
All the best and thanks
Peter

Comment: Please post table schema,sample data,expected result and the query that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Since the table schema was not provided, I assumed the below table schema to answer your question..

Table- Marked:
`UserID int,
 mindate date`

Table- Data:
`UserID int,
 data_date date`

Considering UserID as the primary column to join the tables, here is the query

```
SELECT D.UserID, M.mindate, count(D.data_date) from Marked M
join Data D on M.UserID = D.UserID 
where M.mindate <= D.data_date and D.data_date <= from_unixtime(unix_timestamp());
```

Depending on the `'Date'` datatype in your table, the where clause needs to be changed..

Comment: Sorry.. Please see my new post!